# How to Pass Value From template to js file in lwc salesforce?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have following two lines of code in template:

```
<lightning-button icon-name="utility:download"  onclick={handleExportAction} alternative-text="Export Data"></lightning-button>

<lightning-combobox name="sortOrder" value={value}  options={options} onchange={handleChange} style="width: 200px;margin-left:20px" ></lightning-combobox>
```

And two functions in Js File:

```
handleChange(event) {
      const select = event.detail.value;
}
handleExportAction(event) {
const select = event.detail.value;
}
```

I want value of combobox in handleExportAction function. How i can achieve this Please suggest me i am new lwc.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the value in attribute named **value** which you defined on your template on **onchange** event so that you can use in your **handleExportAction** handler.

```
@track value = 'new';
    handleChange(event) {
            // Get the string of the "value" attribute on the selected option
            const selectedOption = event.detail.value;
            alert(`Option selected with value: ${selectedOption}`);
            this.value = event.detail.value;
        }
    }
```

You can use that variable as:-

```
handleExportAction(event) {
const select = this.value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bro! You Save me.tnx